# OpenSSL crashes while calling SSL_new() Library function

Tags: c++, openssl

I am working with OpenSSL Library. When I execute the project I am facing crash issue from this line of the source code:
m_pSslFd = SSL_new(m_pCtx);

Declaration and initialization part is correct. Execution is working fine when this library method is called first time.  But it crashes while this library method is called second time.
I am giving gdb back trace for this crash

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003dee876285 in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003dee879415 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003dee87a9a1 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00000032c1c6abee in CRYPTO_malloc () from /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
#4  0x00000032c202986a in ssl3_new () from /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
#5  0x00000032c203bfae in dtls1_new () from /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
#6  0x00000032c204534c in SSL_new () from /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
#7  0x00007ffff7882bf7 in DTLSCore::DoDTLSClientNegotiation (this=0x858940, iFd=@0x7fff635fd3bc, speer=...)at src/afg/DTLSCore.cpp:236
```

Any suggestion will be helpful for me. Thank You.

Comment: You are doing something wrong, check your sockets are properly handled. Additionally with that backtrace there is not enough information.

Comment: valgrind will sure help

Comment: I have figured out actual problem and solved it today. Thanks Raistmaj , there was a issue in my socket management. Thanks to Vladimir Kunschikov too, I have learnt about a great memory monitoring tool.

Comment: @RajibTheKing  can u mention how sockets mismanagement caused the above crash, since we also facing the same problem and we also use sockets. If u could explain it would helpful.